# Regular expression match multiple group

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm really bad with regex. I have this string with tokens that I want to split into array. For example:

```
var someStr = "Hello {{{user.fname}}} {{{user.lname}}}, how are you. {{{someVar}}}"
```

Splits into;

```
var result = ["Hello ", "{{{user.fname}}}}", " ", "{{{user.lname}}}", ", how are you. ", "{{{someVar}}}"]
```

So far, I tried `someStr.match(/(.*?)({{{(.*?)}}})(.*?)/g)` which resulted into:

```
["Hello {{{user.fname}}}", " {{{user.lname}}}", ", how are you. {{{someVar}}}"]
```

Not exactly what I'm trying to get.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kG6zI5/3)

```
var re = /[^{}]+|[{]{3}[^}]+[}]{3}/g; 
var str = 'Hello {{{user.fname}}} {{{user.lname}}}, how are you. {{{someVar}}}';
str.match(re);
 //outputs ["Hello ", "{{{user.fname}}}", " ", "{{{user.lname}}}", ", how are you. ", "{{{someVar}}}"]
```

As you may noticed the expression  `[^{}]+|[{]{3}[^}]+[}]{3}` it is divided in 2 using `|`

- `|` means OR
- `[^{}]+` it matches all the characters that do not start `{}` it is also possible to match exactly that it is needed like `[\w\.\s,]+`
- `[{]{3}[^}]+[}]{3}` the second part of the expression matches the characters that within exactly 3 `{{{` `}}}`

Comment: Now, it looks like mine :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj don't see it but my answer came first but thanks for supporting my answer are valid

Comment: @Dalorzo what he means is that your edit came after his answer

Answer (score 2):

You may also consider `split`ting your string.

```
var s = 'Hello {{{user.fname}}} {{{user.lname}}}, how are you. {{{someVar}}}',
    r = s.split(/({{{[^}]+}}})/).filter(Boolean);

console.log(r); 

[ 'Hello ',
  '{{{user.fname}}}',
  ' ',
  '{{{user.lname}}}',
  ', how are you. ',
  '{{{someVar}}}' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
> var someStr = "Hello {{{user.fname}}} {{{user.lname}}}, how are you. {{{someVar}}}"
> someStr.match(/{{{[^}]*}}}|[^{}]+/g)
[ 'Hello ',
  '{{{user.fname}}}',
  ' ',
  '{{{user.lname}}}',
  ', how are you. ',
  '{{{someVar}}}' ]
```

This `{{{[^}]*}}}` regex would match all the strings that  starts with `{{{` and ends with `}}}`, `|`(*OR*) this `[^{}]+` would match all the characters not of `{` or `}` one or more times from the remaining part.